# caret (text insertion point) handling with vanillaJS

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to set & get caret (text insertion point) position & range with vanillaJS in 2020+? every feature that I have found is either obsolete, deprecated or it is in the experimental process. :\

for instance, say you have a "ABC" text in a text area element and you want to remove B  with a virtual backspace btn. I have been able to manage that using 'selectionStart' (which apparently it is deprecated), but after placing the caret and clicking the virtual btn, the caret will jump to the end of the text (in this case after C: AC|). Whereas  it should have been remained between them: A|C

Comment: `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Aren't they deprecated?

Comment: I don’t think so: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) seems to be current.